# How do you automatically update a string variable when a user types in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I have a string variable and UITextView, when a user type something in the UITextView, the string must be updated automatically, so that it's value changes as UITextView's does. What I mean is this code should automatically change the string.

```
myString.String = textView.text;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a `delegate` to your `UITextView` and implement the `textViewDidChange:` method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.myString = textView.text;
}
```

(assuming that `myString` is a property of your delegate)

Comment: `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    
    MYtextView.text = normalTextLayer_.string;
}`

Comment: actually myString is CATextLayer , and does not change ! when I type

Comment: Then use `myString.string = textView.text`.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `myString` is an NSString* variable, you just need to call the following assignment once:

```
myString = textView.text;
```

Then `myString` points to `textView.text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.String = textView.text;
```